# Include in "static" also the domain and protocol for loading static file using external sources

Tags: django, templates

I need to load an image from the server in an email.

```
<img src="{% static 'img/brand.png' %}">
```

doesn't work because the domain is ignored. I get:

```
http:///static/img/brand.png"
```

I can add a direct link, but I prefer to use `static`, in case I modify the default url/folder.

Comment: What is the value of your STATIC_URL setting?

Comment: @DanielRoseman  STATIC_URL = '/static/'